# How to get data from a three dimension form input name array

Tags: php, html

I have a form below,

The select name contains the fixtureId, whether it's home or away and the teamId `fixture[id][home/away][teamid]` and the selected value is the score:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <select name="fixture[1][home][5]">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <select name="fixture[1][away][10]">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

and I want to access the select name values combined with the selected value to output this in two foreach loops:

```
echo $fixtureId."-".$venue."-".$teamId."-".$score;
```

**PHP**

```
foreach($_POST['fixture'] as $fixtureId => $fixtureArray){

    foreach($fixtureArray as $venue => $scoreArray){

        echo $fixtureId."-".$venue;

        $teamId =  key($scoreArray[0]); 
        $score = $scoreArray[0];    

    }   
}
```

**$scoreArray**

```
Array
(
    [10] => 0
)
```

**The Problem**

At the moment `$fixtureId` and `$venue` work as expected but I cannot get the score and Team Id even though they are in the `$scoreArray`?!

Team Id should be 10 and Score should be 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you have choosen the first option and we are dealing with first select ...

```
foreach($_POST['fixture'] as $fixtureId => $fixtureArray){
// Now $textureId = 1; $fixtureArray = array("home"=> array(5=> 0));

    foreach($fixtureArray as $venue => $scoreArray){
    // Now $venue = "home"; $scoreArray = array(5 => 0); therefore ...

        echo $fixtureId."-".$venue;

        // There is NO index 0, so there is no key for it
        $teamId =  key($scoreArray[0]); 
        // Again, There is NO index 0
        $score = $scoreArray[0];    

    }   
}
```

Use `print_r` everytime you are not sure about the indexes of your array.

**To fix this**: Why don't you simply use another `foreach`?

```
foreach($_POST['fixture'] as $fixtureId => $fixtureArray){
    print_r($fixtureArray)

    foreach($fixtureArray as $venue => $scoreArray){
        print_r($scoreArray);
        echo $fixtureId."-".$venue;

        foreach($scoreArray as $teamId => $score)
        {
            echo($teamId."-".$score);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will bet you are not going deep enough. Try this before your `foreach()` loop:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST['fixture'], true).'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this I've tested this code

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';
    foreach($_POST['fixture'] as $fixtureId => $fixtureArray) {
        foreach($fixtureArray as $venue => $scoreArray) {
            echo '<pre>';print_r($scoreArray);echo '</pre>';
            //echo $fixtureId."-".$venue;
            //echo $scoreArray;
            foreach ($scoreArray as $scoreValue) {
                echo "fixtureId ".$fixtureId."-"." venue ".$venue." score value ".$scoreValue."<br />";
            }
            /*$teamId =  key($scoreArray[0]);
            $score = $scoreArray[0];*/

        }
    }
```

This is your code I just update few things. It worked.